# Calculations à la Emacs Rocks -- with `multiple-cursors`

Tags: calc

In [this](http://emacsrocks.com/e13.html) "Emacs Rocks" video relating to the library `multiple-cursors` ( https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el ), the author demonstrates a way of swiftly performing calculations, getting the result in the main window (not in the mini buffer). However, he does not explain what commands are being used. I haven't been able to replicate them, having consulted the available documentation.

Any ideas on how he does it?

Comment: He does explain what commands are being used, by the way: just look at the list under the embedded video.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea is to evaluate some Elisp inline and replace it with the result. It looks like he did it with a [custom function](https://github.com/magnars/.emacs.d/blob/master/defuns/lisp-defuns.el) he defined and bound to `C-x C-e`.

Note that `C-x C-e` is bound to `eval-last-sexp` by default, which does something very similar. It evaluates the s-expression just before your cursor. If you call it with a prefix argument, it will paste the result into the current buffer, but it won't delete the expression. So play around with it:

```
(* 100 200)
```

Put your cursor at the end of that and do `C-u C-x C-e` to get:

```
(* 100 200)20000
```

Comment: Great. Thanks for the answer and explanation.

Comment: The latest version of `smex` causes some trouble invoking this function for all cursors, but it works fine when you bind it to a key chord.

Answer (score 6):

The [same](http://emacsrocks.com/e13.html) Emacs Rocks page links to [an implementation of `eval-and-replace`](https://github.com/magnars/.emacs.d/blob/master/defuns/lisp-defuns.el) used to replace a sexp with its value in this episode.